# problem in setting image over a background image android

Tags: android

i have image-view in my xml for setting the image over a background image at a specified place of back ground image i set it for one emulator and it works but when i launch other emulator of different size image-view change it corresponding position with respect to background image so how to set image view over a background image so that imageview not changes its position for any size of screen 
i am providing my code ...thanks in advance..

here is my **splash.xml** file ,button and imageview changes its position w.r.t. background image..for diffrent size screen emulator

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/TheSplashLayout"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/splashmodified"
  >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="60sp" 
        android:layout_height="60sp" 
        android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_marginTop="120sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55sp"    
        />


    <Button 
         android:text="SUBMIT" 
         android:id="@+id/submitt"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="75px"
         android:layout_marginTop="300px"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not understand the question, you might consider uploading some images and giving us links to them. Only thing I can tell is that you must avoid using `px` when indicating any dimensions. This will make your views look different on every device, that you probably don't want.

Comment: then what should i use in plase of px??if i use sp in place of px then also problem is not solved..

Comment: @saurabh, you should use `dp` (density-independent pixels) instead of `px` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: You can use dp, sp or dip. You may take a look at this post to make it absolutely clear:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: @Andrei Sfat no difference takes place when using dp,sp or dip in the layout view

Comment: Check the the link I've posted above

Answer (score 0):

use `dip` instead of `px` and `sp`.

Your xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/TheSplashLayout"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/splashmodified"
  >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="60dip" 
        android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"

        android:layout_marginTop="120dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
        android:background="@drawable/a_thumb"
        />


    <Button 
         android:text="SUBMIT" 
         android:id="@+id/submitt"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="300dip"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Error in  android:background="@drawable/a_thumb"

Comment: here a_thumb is nothing but the i=name of image in drawable folder. instead of a_thumb give your image name